# Asp.net MVC 3 Conditional Model Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a parent class and a child class, parent has 1 member that his of type child class. Both classes inherit IValidatableObject and validate their own properties, as I want child class to be reusable.

```
public class Parent : IValidateable
{
    Public ChildClass Child {get; set;}
    Public bool ValidateChild {get; set;}

     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    }
}

public class Child : IValidatable
{
    Public string Name {get; set;}

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      //This shouldn't fire if parent.ValidateChild is false
    }
}
```

The problem is the child class property of the parent class should only validate if the ValiddateChild property is true

How do I prevent the child object from validating when ValidateChild is false?

Comment: Are you doing anything in the parent to cause the child to be validated?

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to have custom validation, or you can check some external frameworks like [this](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) and see if this helps.